# call has_many without condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Problem

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many: images , conditions: { size: 'small' }
end
```

Now, I want to access `product.images` without `condition`. Is there anyway ? I think this is very general thing so may be  something like  `unscoped` types of method.

I know i can do something like below.

```
def all_images 
  Image.where(product_id: self.id)
end
```

This isn't okay to create such type of methods in all models for all such class methods which contains `conditions` scoping. I usually call methods without condition when i want to display it in admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot easily do it. And for a good reason, if you ever need "all" items on collection, why to add conditions in the first place?

If you want to load only some members of collection, they way to go is to define additional association.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   # has_many :small_images, -> { where size: 'small' }, class: 'Image' # <= Rails 4
   has_many :small_images , conditions: { size: 'small' }, class: 'Image'
   has_many :images
end
```

I think it is also more clear now, you call `product.images` for all images, and `product.small_images` for small ones.

Comment: Probably even better idea would be to create a scope `small` on images. Then you could call `products.images.small` without modifying Product class at all.

Comment: @BroiSatse: I agree, but the question was about conditions in associations. This was just for the sake of example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unscoped` method:

```
product.images.unscoped
```

Note however, that this will remove all scopes from association proxy, together with default model scope.